# Postgresql unable to change the data type of a column

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am new to Postgresql, and I am trying to change the data type of a column from `Integer to Varchar(20)`, but I get strange error:

```
   ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying <> integer :
      No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). 
    You might need to add explicit type casts.********** Error **********
```

The script I wrote to create the table is:

```
CREATE TABLE LOGIN(
USERNAME INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK(USERNAME != NULL),
PASSWORD VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL CHECK(PASSWORD <>'' AND USERNAME != NULL)
);
```

This is the script I used to modify the column from Integer to Varchar:

```
ALTER TABLE LOGIN ALTER COLUMN USERNAME TYPE varchar(20);
```

I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Is the table empty, or does it have data?

Comment: NOT NULL does the trick, no need to add another not null attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the error is the useless additional check constraint (`<> null`) that you have:

> operator does not exist: character varying <> integer :

refers to the condition `USERNAME != NULL` in both of your check constraints.

(the "not equals" operator in SQL is `<>` and `!=` gets re-written into that)

So you first need to get rid of those check constraints. The default generated name for that check would be `login_username_check`, so the following will most probably work:

```
alter table login 
   drop constraint login_username_check;
```

The other check is most probably `login_check`:

```
alter table login 
   drop constraint login_check;
```

Once those check constraints are dropped you can alter the data type:

```
ALTER TABLE LOGIN 
    ALTER COLUMN USERNAME set data TYPE varchar(20);
```

Now you need to re-add the constraint for the password:

```
alter table login 
    add constraint check_password check (password <> '');
```

If for some reason the generated constraint names are different then the ones I assumes, you can find the names using:

```
select c.conname, c.consrc
from pg_constraint c
  join pg_class t on c.conrelid = t.oid
  join pg_namespace n on t.relnamespace = n.oid
where t.relname = 'login'
  and n.nspname = 'public'; --<< change here for the correct schema name
```

---

As jarlh has already commented, defining a column as `NOT NULL` is enough. There is no need to add another "not null" check. Plus: the check is wrong anyway. You can't compare a value against `null` using `=` or `<>`. To test for a not null value you need to use `IS NOT NULL`. The correct way to write an explicit check constraint would be

```
 username check (username is not null)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `USING expression`. It allows you to define value conversion:

```
ALTER TABLE LOGIN ALTER COLUMN USERNAME TYPE varchar(20) USING ...expression...;
```

From [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html):

> The optional USING clause specifies how to compute the new column
>   value from the old; if omitted, the default conversion is the same as
>   an assignment cast from old data type to new. A USING clause must be
>   provided if there is no implicit or assignment cast from old to new
>   type.

Comment: Won't work because of the (useless) check constraint `USERNAME != NULL`. The error message actually "points" to that constraint because of the `<>` operator in it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in USERNAME's CHECK constraint. You may get a way out of it using catalog pg_constraint somehow like that:

```
SELECT conname, consrc
  FROM pg_constraint
 WHERE conrelid =
    (SELECT oid
       FROM pg_class
      WHERE relname LIKE 'login');
```

In a field 'consrc' you may notice that constraints actually look like "(username <> NULL::integer)", and it brings an error when you try to change column type from integer to varchar.

To remove constraints use

```
ALTER TABLE LOGIN DROP CONSTRAINT login_username_check;
ALTER TABLE LOGIN DROP CONSTRAINT login_check;
```

where 'login_username_check' and 'login_check' are connames you got from query above (be careful and doublecheck that names).

After that you should try to

```
ALTER TABLE LOGIN ALTER COLUMN USERNAME TYPE varchar(20);
```

This should work if your table has no data in it. If it doesn't, add a

```
ALTER TABLE dev.tests_LOGIN ALTER COLUMN USERNAME TYPE varchar(20) USING USERNAME::VARCHAR;
```

Than you probably want to restore PASSWORD<>'' check, so you'll have to do one more alter to bring it back. Good luck!

Some PostgreSQL documentation you may find handy:

[pg_constraint doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-constraint.html)

[alter doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-alter.html)

PS: As mentioned above, you don't need to get a constraint (!=NULL) check when you already have NOT NULL in column description. Also, NULL checks are a bit different. Quick illustration:

```
SELECT (NULL = NULL);
SELECT (NULL != NULL);
SELECT (NULL IS NULL);
SELECT (NULL IS NOT NULL);
```